# Friend function C++

Tags: c++, class

Why doesn't this work?

I use friendly function in my code but there is an error so I can not find it. please help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class Circle{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Circle(int x1=5){
        x=x1;
        friend std:ostream & operator<<(const Circle & c, std::ostream & os)
        {
            return os<<c.x
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    Circle s;
    cout<< s;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four problems:

1. You've defined the friend function inside the constructor. Move it outside so that it's its own function.
2. Replace `std:ostream` with `std::ostream`
3. Swap the order of the parameters.
4. Add a semicolon after `return os<<c.x`

Final result:

```
class Circle{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Circle(int x1=5){
        x=x1;
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Circle & c)
    {
        return os<<c.x;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    friend std:ostream & operator<<(const Circle & c, std::ostream & os)
    {
        return os<<c.x
    }
```

you should declare this function outside the constructor.

Comment: One other minor detail: missing the semicolon after `os<<c.x`.

Comment: sorry, i just copied the function from the code posted by @Mat
Two other mistakes are there in that function which i didn't mark that is the semicolon after `os<<c.x` and the order of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

The friend function needs to be declared at the same level as the constructor, not inside it.